# 10baseT and 10baseFX difference

Tags: fiber, cabling, utp

What is the difference between 10baseT and 10baseFx are those types of cables or the boxes that are used to plug the cables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*10BaseT* and *10BaseFx* are standards of connectivity for Ethernet.

10BaseT defines the use of twisted pair cabling (UTP / STP) for Ethernet, that includes cable features, male (in cable) and female (in wall boxes) connectors, max distances, etc.

10BaseFx defines the use of fiber optics for Ethernet, including type of fiber, max distances, connectors (in cable and in wall boxes), etc.

Comment: Small correction. 10BASE-T doesn't define the use of UTP. Rather it defines the use of twisted pair. STP is an allowable option for use with 10BASE-T.

Answer (score 4):

10BASE-FX is no official IEEE 802.3 standard - various, non-compatible versions may exist. The 10 Mbit/s standard PHY is (was) **10BASE-FL**. Fast Ethernet has 100BASE-FX as common standard.

As a collective term for the 10 Mbit/s fiber standards (FOIRL, 10BASE-FL, -FB and -FP), **10BASE-F** is used. Appending an *x* is misleading as the *X* indicates 4b/5b or 8b/10b PCS encoding as in 100BASE-TX, 1000BASE-LX and so on.

These are *physical layer* standards that define the way data is transmitted on the wire/fiber, what kind of cables are required etc.

10BASE-T requires category 3 cables, 10BASE-FL runs on pretty much any fiber, usually FDDI 62.5 µm multimode fiber was used. 100BASE-FX also used FDDI fiber but was also very often deployed over OM1.

Later and faster physical layers require better, "faster" copper cable categories or fiber types.

The "boxes" you refer to can be any type of network equipment: repeaters, hubs, switches, routers, media converters, ...

Answer (score 0):

They are both for Ethernet's 10 Mbps transmission speed.

10BASE-T, one of several physical media specified in the IEEE 802.3 standard for Ethernet local area networks (LANs), is ordinary telephone twisted pair wire.

10BaseF is an implementation of Ethernet 802.3 over fiber optic cabling. 10BaseF is not often a permanent solution because the data rate is so low and the cabling so expensive in comparison to using UTP.